# Add UIImageView objects to an array (Objective C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uiimageview

I've read the other threads about arrays of UIImageView-objects, but I can't get it to work. Note that I'm completely new to Objective-c.

I have some UIImageView objects declared in the .h - file like this:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *obj1;
```

I also have an array declared at the same place:

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSArray *arr;
```

In the viewDidLoad-method I want to add obj1 to arr. How can I do that?

I've tested to initialize arr and add objects to it, but it doesn't work.

```
_arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

[_arr addObjects: obj1];
```

Hank

Comment: IBOutlet means that you're connecting that object to the Interface Builder (hence IB). An array is not something that gets connected there. You'll have to define it differently to hook it up.

Comment: you should accept one of answers, if they've helped, or no one will help you next time :)

Comment: Sry. Still a newbie. Now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make sure in debugger that `_arr` is not `nil`. You need to declare it as

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arr;
```

since arr is not a ui control on view controller, you do not need to add `IBOutlet`.

Also, your view controller posses it, so it should be `strong` rather than `weak`.

You also should use `NSMutableArray` instead of `NSArray`, since only the first one can be used for adding objects, and this is how you say to the compiler of the type of this object

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSArray *arr;
```

to

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *arr;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add UIImageView Object in your Array you can do that.But the thing is if your want to add object in NSArrar after its initialization than you have to declare NSMutableArray  as you can add and remove object in that than the addObject method would work.

Also their is no need to declare NSArray of NSMutableArray as IBOutlet.